# Java EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION while executing batch update from Servlet

Tags: java, sql, exception, servlets

I wanted to insert multiple records in MS Access file from java Servlet. The batchupdate runs perfectly for first 10 records but the next batch update gives the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6966ef76, pid=5688, tid=5368
#
# JRE version: 6.0_33-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.8-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [odbcjt32.dll+0x1ef76]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\SOFT\Eclipse IDE for Java EE\hs_err_pid5688.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Here is my sample code I am using:

```
statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);

            for(int i = 0; i < DataCache.seriesTable.getRows().size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<String> row = DataCache.seriesTable.getRow(i);
                for(int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
                    statement.setString(j+1, row.get(j));
                }
                statement.addBatch();

                if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
                    statement.executeBatch(); // Execute every 5 items.
                }
            }
            int[] n = statement.executeBatch();
```

Any idea how to get rid of this issue?

Here are the contents of "D:\SOFT\Eclipse IDE for Java EE\hs_err_pid5688.log" file.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6966ef76, pid=5688, tid=5368
#
# JRE version: 6.0_33-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.8-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [odbcjt32.dll+0x1ef76]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x184c9400):  JavaThread "http-8080-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5368, stack(0x18b60000,0x18bb0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0000000e, ECX=0x0000000a, EDX=0x00000005
ESP=0x18baf258, EBP=0x18baf274, ESI=0x18940340, EDI=0x189402d8
EIP=0x6966ef76, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x18baf258)
0x18baf258:   00000000 18940340 189402d8 00000000
0x18baf268:   00000000 00000001 00000001 18baf2a8
0x18baf278:   6966f95b 00000000 0000000e 00000001
0x18baf288:   00000001 000000ff 00000000 184ea710
0x18baf298:   00000000 00000000 0029d830 0029b240
0x18baf2a8:   18baf2e8 700be766 189402d8 0000000e
0x18baf2b8:   00000001 00000001 00000001 000000ff
0x18baf2c8:   00000000 184ea710 00000000 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x6966ef76)
0x6966ef56:   52 e8 34 ea ff ff 85 c0 0f 84 56 ff ff ff 66 83
0x6966ef66:   7d 08 00 8b 40 20 75 14 83 f8 ff 75 08 8b 45 24
0x6966ef76:   83 38 ff 75 07 c7 45 f0 01 00 00 00 0f bf 4d 14
0x6966ef86:   6a 00 6a 00 51 6a 02 53 56 8d 87 30 03 00 00 50 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0000000e is an unknown value
ECX=0x0000000a is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000005 is an unknown value
ESP=0x18baf258 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x184c9400
EBP=0x18baf274 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x184c9400
ESI=0x18940340 is an unknown value
EDI=0x189402d8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x18b60000,0x18bb0000],  sp=0x18baf258,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [odbcjt32.dll+0x1ef76]  SQLNumParams+0x946
C  [odbcjt32.dll+0x1f95b]  SQLBindParameter+0x9b
C  [ODBC32.dll+0x2e766]  SQLBindParameter+0x1df
C  [ODBC32.dll+0x2e5fd]  SQLBindParameter+0x76
C  [JdbcOdbc.dll+0x2c24]  Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_bindInParameterString+0x106
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.bindInParameterString(JII[BII[B[B[J)V+0
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLBindInParameterString(JIIII[B[B[J)V+110
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setChar(IIILjava/lang/String;)V+135
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setString(ILjava/lang/String;)V+39
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(ILjava/lang/Object;II)V+376
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(ILjava/lang/Object;I)V+5
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.emulateExecuteBatch()[I+268
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatchUpdate()[I+564
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeBatch()[I+1
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.saveSeriesData()V+100
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.extractSeriesData(Ljava/sql/Connection;)V+149
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+278
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+139
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+376
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+804
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+365
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+158
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)V+514
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)Z+82
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run()V+41
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfadcb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c3e1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfaf71]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfafcb]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb5569]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1190a4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14108c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0x51174]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b3f5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b3c8]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.bindInParameterString(JII[BII[B[B[J)V+0
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLBindInParameterString(JIIII[B[B[J)V+110
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setChar(IIILjava/lang/String;)V+135
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setString(ILjava/lang/String;)V+39
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(ILjava/lang/Object;II)V+376
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(ILjava/lang/Object;I)V+5
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.emulateExecuteBatch()[I+268
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatchUpdate()[I+564
j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeBatch()[I+1
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.saveSeriesData()V+100
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.extractSeriesData(Ljava/sql/Connection;)V+149
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+278
j  com.SDAM.servlets.Upload_Data_File.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+139
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+376
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+804
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+365
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+158
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)V+514
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)Z+82
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run()V+41
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x184aa400 JavaThread "http-8080-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3684, stack(0x18df0000,0x18e40000)]
  0x184a9c00 JavaThread "http-8080-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2220, stack(0x18da0000,0x18df0000)]
  0x184a9400 JavaThread "http-8080-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5920, stack(0x18d50000,0x18da0000)]
  0x184a9000 JavaThread "http-8080-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5112, stack(0x18c00000,0x18c50000)]
  0x184ed400 JavaThread "http-8080-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4956, stack(0x18bb0000,0x18c00000)]
=>0x184c9400 JavaThread "http-8080-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5368, stack(0x18b60000,0x18bb0000)]
  0x184c3c00 JavaThread "http-8080-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5892, stack(0x18b10000,0x18b60000)]
  0x1851c800 JavaThread "TP-Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3596, stack(0x18ac0000,0x18b10000)]
  0x1851c400 JavaThread "TP-Processor4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4256, stack(0x18a70000,0x18ac0000)]
  0x1851bc00 JavaThread "TP-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5900, stack(0x18a20000,0x18a70000)]
  0x18520800 JavaThread "TP-Processor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5576, stack(0x188d0000,0x18920000)]
  0x184af000 JavaThread "TP-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=700, stack(0x18880000,0x188d0000)]
  0x184b7800 JavaThread "http-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2364, stack(0x18830000,0x18880000)]
  0x184afc00 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3148, stack(0x180e0000,0x18130000)]
  0x18400c00 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=708, stack(0x18090000,0x180e0000)]
  0x0194c400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1964, stack(0x17f30000,0x17f80000)]
  0x01952800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5404, stack(0x17e80000,0x17ed0000)]
  0x0193a400 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5256, stack(0x17e30000,0x17e80000)]
  0x01939400 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5760, stack(0x17dc0000,0x17e10000)]
  0x01937400 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3956, stack(0x17d70000,0x17dc0000)]
  0x0192b000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5712, stack(0x17c60000,0x17cb0000)]
  0x0192a000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5516, stack(0x17c10000,0x17c60000)]
  0x018fa400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5284, stack(0x17bc0000,0x17c10000)]
  0x018f8c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3564, stack(0x17b70000,0x17bc0000)]
  0x003e9400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=448, stack(0x00370000,0x003c0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x018f5800 VMThread [stack: 0x17b20000,0x17b70000] [id=3760]
  0x0194e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x18040000,0x18090000] [id=1532]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4992K, used 4236K [0x039e0000, 0x03f40000, 0x08f30000)
  eden space 4480K,  83% used [0x039e0000, 0x03d87c10, 0x03e40000)
  from space 512K,  96% used [0x03e40000, 0x03ebb4f0, 0x03ec0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x03ec0000, 0x03ec0000, 0x03f40000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 6149K [0x08f30000, 0x099e0000, 0x139e0000)
   the space 10944K,  56% used [0x08f30000, 0x09531738, 0x09531800, 0x099e0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10772K [0x139e0000, 0x145e0000, 0x179e0000)
   the space 12288K,  87% used [0x139e0000, 0x144653b0, 0x14465400, 0x145e0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x01960000, 0x01af8000, 0x03960000)
 total_blobs=697 nmethods=539 adapters=102 free_code_cache=31904832 largest_free_block=192

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00425000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x77660000 - 0x7779c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77310000 - 0x773e4000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75a20000 - 0x75a6a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x777f0000 - 0x77890000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77440000 - 0x774ec000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76f80000 - 0x76f99000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x75c20000 - 0x75cc1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x75e00000 - 0x75ec9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x773f0000 - 0x7743e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x774f0000 - 0x774fa000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x75b80000 - 0x75c1d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x76d10000 - 0x76d2f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76e20000 - 0x76eec000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x73c40000 - 0x73c72000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x756c0000 - 0x7570b000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d370000 - 0x6d399000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jdwp.dll
0x6d690000 - 0x6d696000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\npt.dll
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d200000 - 0x6d207000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x777a0000 - 0x777d5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x75df0000 - 0x75df6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x73f20000 - 0x73f30000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x75200000 - 0x7523c000     C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
0x750c0000 - 0x75104000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x71be0000 - 0x71be8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x71bd0000 - 0x71be0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x71bb0000 - 0x71bc2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x003c0000 - 0x003d9000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x73700000 - 0x7371c000     C:\Windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x736f0000 - 0x736f7000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x73590000 - 0x735c8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x71ba0000 - 0x71ba6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74d40000 - 0x74d45000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d550000 - 0x6d559000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
0x6d780000 - 0x6d788000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x75900000 - 0x75a1c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75870000 - 0x7587c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x751f0000 - 0x751f6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x75240000 - 0x75256000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74fe0000 - 0x7501b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74e10000 - 0x74e27000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75760000 - 0x7576b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x75740000 - 0x7574c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x6d360000 - 0x6d36d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\JdbcOdbc.dll
0x70090000 - 0x7011a000     C:\Windows\system32\ODBC32.dll
0x72840000 - 0x72878000     C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll
0x753e0000 - 0x753f7000     C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
0x74f20000 - 0x74f5d000     C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
0x6ffa0000 - 0x6ffe5000     C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE14\ACEODBC.DLL
0x733c0000 - 0x73463000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.5570_none_509463cabcb6ef2a\MSVCR90.dll
0x75b00000 - 0x75b7b000     C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
0x77280000 - 0x772d7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x745b0000 - 0x7474e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\COMCTL32.dll
0x75ed0000 - 0x76b19000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x77500000 - 0x7765c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x5cca0000 - 0x5de7e000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\mso.dll
0x19070000 - 0x192b0000     C:\Windows\system32\msi.dll
0x61e60000 - 0x6226f000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\Cultures\office.odf
0x73990000 - 0x7399f000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\1033\ACEODBCI.DLL
0x747d0000 - 0x747db000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEERR.DLL
0x61ab0000 - 0x61cca000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACECORE.DLL
0x73330000 - 0x733be000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.5570_none_509463cabcb6ef2a\MSVCP90.dll
0x76ef0000 - 0x76f7f000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x624c0000 - 0x62592000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\1033\ACEWSTR.DLL
0x709f0000 - 0x70a0e000     C:\Windows\system32\odbccp32.dll
0x74cb0000 - 0x74cb9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x756a0000 - 0x756ba000     C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x74470000 - 0x744b0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x58770000 - 0x5cc9a000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\MSORES.DLL
0x72b60000 - 0x72b76000     C:\Windows\system32\DavClnt.DLL
0x747e0000 - 0x747e8000     C:\Windows\system32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x60120000 - 0x60382000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\1033\MSOINTL.DLL
0x741c0000 - 0x741d3000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x696a0000 - 0x69743000     C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE14\ACEEXCL.DLL
0x70470000 - 0x704a2000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\1033\ACEINTL.DLL
0x76d90000 - 0x76e13000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x71d90000 - 0x71ee7000     C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
0x69650000 - 0x6969e000     C:\Windows\system32\odbcjt32.dll
0x5fc30000 - 0x5fdb5000     C:\Windows\system32\msjet40.dll
0x693c0000 - 0x69458000     C:\Windows\system32\mswstr10.dll
0x71450000 - 0x71456000     C:\Windows\system32\odbcji32.dll
0x709d0000 - 0x709e1000     C:\Windows\system32\msjter40.dll
0x70940000 - 0x70946000     C:\Windows\system32\MSJINT40.DLL
0x692e0000 - 0x69328000     C:\Windows\system32\msjtes40.dll
0x1ded0000 - 0x1dedb000     C:\Windows\system32\VBAJET32.DLL
0x230d0000 - 0x23132000     C:\Windows\system32\expsrv.dll
0x777e0000 - 0x777e5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:52879 -Dcatalina.base=D:\SOFT\Eclipse IDE for Java EE\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32 -Dwtp.deploy=D:\SOFT\Eclipse IDE for Java EE\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\endorsed -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
CLASSPATH=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib\jsp-api.jar;.;
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Ruby192\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;E:\ApacheAnt\bin;D:\SOFT\Eclipse IDE for Java EE;
USERNAME=khawar.raza
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 3088716k(1133348k free), swap 6175668k(3980664k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.8-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_33-b03), built on May  9 2012 09:39:57 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Thu Jun 21 12:32:43 2012
elapsed time: 54 seconds
```

Comment: could you maybe give us the contents of `D:\SOFT\Eclipse IDE for Java EE\hs_err_pid5688.log` ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution. Actually I was using MS Access as DBMS which is very slow and I think this was the real issue. The insertion speed of Java was incompatible with MS Access. MS Access overwhelmed with huge amount of data as I am inserting more than 200000 records at a time and due to this overwhelming, MS Access could not handle such huge amount of data and ACCESS VIOLATION was being raised. I replaced MS Access with MySQl and now its looking fine.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

try closing when done:

```
statement.close();
```

**Edit** sorry, for some reason, I misunderstood your question. From the error message:

`# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.`

I googled for the error, but this is as far as I was able to get:

http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/312-exception_access_violation-0xc0000005.html

Some posts report that it could be a bug in JVM and you need to upgrade. Others suggest a corrupted DLL.

The first thing I would do, is test it on another machine, and move from there.

Not a lot of help, I know !

Comment: It generates error before I can insert all records. I cannot call statement.close() before all the records are not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, saving data from a scraping program.  It was completely random but seemed to happen with increasing frequency.

After a day of trying various things, I finally tried going into Access and doing a Compact and Repair Database.  That seems to have done the trick.  So that may be a solution for someone else also.